# Input Text Size in a container resize

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to create a contact form within a container, but every time I'm trying to test it or resize the browser or used mobile, the text input field doesn't remain on the container. The text field goes beyond the form

```
<div class="col-md-4">      
<div class="thumbnail">
<div class="container">     
<form id="frmContact" action="" method="post">
<div id="mail-status"></div>
<div>
<label style="padding-top:0px;">Name:</label>
<span id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Enter Full Name">
</div>
<div>
<label>Email:</label>
<span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Enter E-mail Address">
</div>
<br>
<div>
<label>Attachment:</label><br/>
<input type="file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<br>
<div>
<label>Subject:</label> 
<span id="subject-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Subject">
</div>
<div>
<label>Content:</label> 
<span id="content-info" class="info"></span><br/>
<textarea name="content" id="content" class="demoInputBox" cols="" rows="5" placeholder="Concerns"></textarea>
<br>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btnAction" />
</div>
</form>
<div id="loader-icon" style="display:none;"><img src="LoaderIcon.gif" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems fine to me? https://jsfiddle.net/1qkm6nc8/

Comment: This may help . `button, input, select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: @DanielH if you try to put size in the text field it will go beyond the form

Comment: @Zionz doesnt work

Comment: @JayGarrick this one, size added + input width css? https://jsfiddle.net/vcshz692/

Comment: @DanielH still doesnt work, text field goes beyond the form

Comment: @DanielH it doesnt store in the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to deal with this kind of approach is to use 
Mediaqueries. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp 
you can use that link as a guide.

You can also use Flex to make it responsive :) hope this helps.